# Changing compression in memory

Tags: command-line, pipe, compression, rar

I have some large files that I need to change the compression type of for input to a program--I need to unrar them and then gzip (or bzip2) them.  However, they're highly compressed files and I don't have the disk space to unrar them fully then gzip them.  Is there any way to pipe the output of decompression via unrar to gzip or some other compression without saving the entire intermediate result to disk?

Answer (score 2):

`man unrar` mentions an option `p`: "Print file to stdout". So, it seems you might extract the file with `unrar` and pipe it to `gzip/bzip2`.

Comment: There's garbage data: `echo jj > a; rar a a.rar a; unrar p a.rar | gzip -9 -f > out.gz; zcat out.gz`

Comment: @warl0ck Yes, add `-ierr` to suppress informational messages. Look at [man unrar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unrar)